# Ansible-Playbook for the Install of mod_ssl, python-passlib and firewalld (and keep them always latest)

Tags: ansible, mod-ssl, centos8

I manage 2 Clients (centos8) with Ansible, and i want to install mod-ssl on the webserver, python-passlib on all hosts and firewalld on all hosts. 
The Playbook should check every time it runs, wheter the 3 packages are the latest available.

I´ve already wrote a playbook, but i get the errormessage, that there is no package with the name "python-passlib"

Is there another name for this package on centos8?
And i think my way to install this mod-ssl package is false as well... Could you guys check my Playbook and give me a hint ? :D

Here´s my playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install different services and keep them up-to-date
    dnf:
      name:
        - firewalld
        - python-passlib
      state: latest 

- hosts: webserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install mod-ssl and keep it up-to-date
    dnf:
      name: mod-ssl


- hosts: webserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Insert a index.php site 
    copy: 
      src: /home/mike/devops_live_demo/index.php
      dest: /var/www/html/
      owner: mike
      mode: '0644'

- hosts: webserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Reboot the Webserver
    reboot:
```

Thank you guys in advance!!
Greetings 
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**python-passlib** was deprecated in later versions of RHEL 7 and removed completely in RHEL 8 (hence also removed in CentOS 8). It might become available in the EPEL repository, however it is not currently there. There is an open RFE for its inclusion [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1755034)

To install python-passlib in the meantime, you can use the Ansible `pip` module and install `passlib`. You could source a 3rd-party packaged RPM of passlib, but I would recommend against this unless you trust the source.

**mod_ssl** can be installed from the RPM repositories, you just need to adjust the package name in your task (you have `mod-ssl`, but it should be `mod_ssl`). You will also need to add `state: latest` if you want it to keep the package up to date:

```
  - name: Install mod-ssl and keep it up-to-date
    dnf:
      name: mod_ssl
    state: latest
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your quick answer!! 

So for the mod_ssl: Do you know, how i have to adjust the package name exactly?

I´m new to ansible and not that familiar with the topic.. for now ;)

Comment: Hi Mike .. sorry I should have been more verbose. Your package name has a hyphen, when it should be an underscore (i.e. `mod_ssl`, not `mod-ssl`). I'll update the answer

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks again, i’ve already tried it with an _ , but i get the same error..

Answer (score 1):

**python3-passlib** is the name package for CentOS 8 (RHEL 8 and its derivatives) and it can be also available for RHEL 9 and its derivatives